# @Cacheable for default spring data jpa methods without overriding them

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

Sry, if my question isn't new but i couldn't find answer.I use Spring Data JPA and Spring Cache.
I have folowing repository

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "Category")
@Cacheable
@Repository
public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {

    Category findByCategory(String Category);
}
```

And i want to cache default CrudRepository methods, like findAll() and etc.
It's work If i override them like this

```
    @CacheConfig(cacheNames = "Category")
    @Cacheable
    @Repository
    public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long> {

        Category findByCategory(String Category);
        List<Category> findAll();

    }
```

But it's not convenient override them every time for every repository.

Is there a way cache defaults spring jpa methods without override them or no such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can do it. Basically, Spring uses Hibernate ORM as the implementation of JPA. Hibernate itself supports caching functionality with it and will integrate better than Spring Cache.

To enable L2 cache, add these properties to your project add the following properties.

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory

and dependencies hibernate-ehcache

Once this is done, all your default methods of JPA like `findOne()`, `findAll()` will be cached.

If you add any custom methods, you can add like below:

`@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value ="true") }) Category findByCategory(String Category);`

To test where default methods are cached, you can use the following properties to see if SQL has been executed.

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

Comment: Just to notice: This version uses the implementation of  Ehcache. You could also use other implementations. I for example like Hazelcast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it